# How to see TestNG test-results xml results from gradle on report portal?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, automation, testng, reportportal

I am using report portal with Kotlin and TestNG and gradle as the build tool

`compile group: 'com.epam.reportportal', name: 'agent-java-testng', version: '4.2.0'`

When I run the tests via gradle wrapper, it generates a bunch of artifacts under build folder after the run. I am specially interested in the `.xml` files contents under `/build/test-results/<gradle task name>/<test class.xml>`

Since it has a `<system-out>` tag with all the standard output. This has useful context around the test failure such as what API calls/flows were triggered before failure.

Is there a way to get this information to show up in report portal?

### build.gradle

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()

    ...
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/epam/reportportal" }
    ...
}


task runTests(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
        useDefaultListeners = false
        listeners << 'com.epam.reportportal.testng.ReportPortalTestNGListener'
        includeGroups System.getProperty('tag', 'NONE')
    }
}
```